# JavaScript: searching for a simple way of returning 'this' instead of 'val=x'

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following function returns `val=ret` instead of `this`. It is complicated and not clear:

```
   getElement: function (nodeId) {

            var ret = null;

            if (nodeId === this._nodeId) {
                ret = this;
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < this._selects.length; i++) {
                    ret = this._selects[i].getElement(nodeId);
                    if (ret) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return (ret);
    },
```

Could you suggest an easier way for that? I tried the following, but you can't
do true/false with `if(this._pages[i].getElement(nodeId)`:

```
   getElement: function (nodeId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this._pages.length; i++) {
                if(this._pages[i].getElement(nodeId){
                    return this;
                }
            }
        return null;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return

```
this._pages[i].getElement(nodeId)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second is not the same, because the first check is missing. (No need for an `else` part if a `return` is in the *then* part.)

```
getElement: function (nodeId) {
    var i, ret;
    if (nodeId === this._nodeId) {
        return this;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < this._selects.length; i++) {
        ret = this._selects[i].getElement(nodeId);
        if (ret) {
            return ret;
        }
    }
    return null;
},
```

Comment: Performance: You need var i only in the for loop! it have to be -> var i = 0; i < this._selects.length; i++

Comment: `i` gets hoisted, so why not declare at the beginning?

Comment: If you leave the for loop the space of i getting free.

Comment: is the `i` the problem? really? it gets anyway (read always through hoisting) declared. even if the for loop is never reached.

Comment: eslint says: error  Unexpected alias 'ret' for 'this'  consistent-this that is the bigges problem, the other doesn't matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126826/discussion-between-post4dirk-and-nina-scholz).